# How can I install Ubuntu on Lenovo G580 IdeaPad?

Tags: boot, lenovo, system-installation

My laptop is a Lenovo G580 IdeaPad.

```
Specs:  
Processor               Intel Core i7 3632QM CPU @ 2.20 GHz  
Installed Memory (RAM)  8.00 GB (7.87 GB usable)  
System type             64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor
```

The GPU is Nividia G610M. How can I install Ubuntu on this laptop?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Turned out all I needed to do was adjust the brightness levels with the f2 and f3 keys. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I had issues booting my computer if I have anything connected to the usb ports (even a simple keyboard and mouse :S) if that doesn't help then try setting `acpi=off` in the boot line of grub.